# why I receive "bad request" in my request by retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to register a user by using retrofit. Where is my mistake?

Here is my interface:

```
public interface ChatRoomAPI {
String BASE_URL="https://karyab-api.herokuapp.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
.build();
 @POST("register")
 Call<RegisterResponse> registerUser(@Body RegisterData registerData);
```

Here is the body of register `pojo` class:

```
public class RegisterData {
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
public String getEmail() {return email;}
public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
public String getPassword() {return password;}
public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
```

Here is the response pojo class:

```
public class RegisterResponse {
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private User user;
@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;
public User getUser() {return user;}
public void setUser(User user) {this.user = user;}
public String getToken() {return token;}
public void setToken(String token) { this.token = token;}
```

Codes in my activity:

```
private void registerUser(RegisterData registerData) {
ChatRoomAPI webService =
ChatRoomAPI.retrofit.create(ChatRoomAPI.class);
Call<RegisterResponse> call = webService.registerUser(registerData);
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<RegisterResponse> call, 
@NonNull Response<RegisterResponse> response) {
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
RegisterResponse body = response.body();
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
body.getToken(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
   try {
String errorBodyJson=response.errorBody().string();
Gson gson=new Gson();
ErrorResponce 
errorResponce=gson.fromJson(errorBodyJson, 
ErrorResponce.class);
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
response.message(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
"Received " + t.getCause() + " items from service",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

I don't know where my mistake is. In postman I get 200 OK but here I get bad request.

It is not complicated but I'm tired to solve it please help me and save my time.

Here is the result in postman:

```
{
"user": {
"id": 26,
"updatedAt": "2019-08-16T16:35:04.347Z",
"createdAt": "2019-08-16T16:35:04.347Z",
"email": null,
"password": null
},
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI...
 }
```

Here is the input in postman.

```
{
"email":"aaaaa",
"password":"11111"
}
```

Comment: can u add retrofit error

Comment: Have you created RegisterData object  & set its both properties with some values?

Comment: @EslamAhmad this code =Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
response.message(); is run and it is "bad request" and response is null

Comment: @SudarshanVidhate it is the code where i call "registerUser"  RegisterData registerData=new RegisterData();
        registerData.setEmail("ali@gmail.com");
        registerData.setPassword("123456789");
        registerUser(registerData);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this by using @FormUrlEncoded

Create class RegResponse

```
public class RegResponse{

@SerializedName("user")
private User user;

@SerializedName("token")
private String token;

public void setUser(User user){
    this.user = user;
}

public User getUser(){
    return user;
}

public void setToken(String token){
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken(){
    return token;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "RegResponse{" + 
        "user = '" + user + '\'' + 
        ",token = '" + token + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}
```

Create Class User

```
public class User{

@SerializedName("createdAt")
private String createdAt;

@SerializedName("password")
private Object password;

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("email")
private Object email;

@SerializedName("updatedAt")
private String updatedAt;

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt){
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getCreatedAt(){
    return createdAt;
}

public void setPassword(Object password){
    this.password = password;
}

public Object getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setEmail(Object email){
    this.email = email;
}

public Object getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt){
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt(){
    return updatedAt;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "User{" + 
        "createdAt = '" + createdAt + '\'' + 
        ",password = '" + password + '\'' + 
        ",id = '" + id + '\'' + 
        ",email = '" + email + '\'' + 
        ",updatedAt = '" + updatedAt + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }
}
```

Create interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST
Call<RegResponse> register(@Url String url, @Field("email") String user, 
 @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Now in your MainActivity

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            reg();
        }
    });


private void reg() {

    try {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        retrofit2.Call<RegResponse> responseBodyCall = 
apiService.register("https://karyab-api.herokuapp.com/register", 
edtUser.getText().toString(), edtPass.getText().toString());
        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<RegResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<RegResponse> call, 
retrofit2.Response<RegResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginAcitivity.this, "Register Succesfully..", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginAcitivity.this, "fail", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<RegResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(" fail ", " is calling");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("exception", ":" + e);
    }
}
```